# Angular, Unable to display Data as a List from firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display data from firebase in angular, but I can't seem to get the list objects from loading and it always leads to a blank with this error
`ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

I've even followed the fire module guide, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my component code

```
import {AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList} from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'querydata',
  templateUrl: './querydata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./querydata.component.css']
})
export class QuerydataComponent implements OnInit {

  courses:any;
  constructor(private db :AngularFireDatabase) {
      
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.db.list('courses').valueChanges().subscribe(courses =>{
       this.courses=courses;
       console.log(this.courses);
     });
  }

}
```

and my template code

```
<p>querydata works!</p>

<ul *ngIf="courses">
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses | async">
        {{ course.value }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'courses' is not observable / async pipe but a value. this.db.list('courses').valueChanges()` would be observable, but su

Does this print something?

```
<li *ngFor="let course of courses">
    {{ course }}
</li>
```

Comment: Nope, causes this error :Property 'JSON' does not exist on type 'QuerydataComponent'.

Comment: Oh yes, of cours.. .how about just {{ course }} ?